# how to get MSISDN number in WAP using PHP?

Tags: php, phone-number, sim-card, wap, msisdn

I have developed a WAP application and I would like to get the MSISDN of the users that visit my site.

My operator has white listed my WAP application.

I am getting MSISDN successfully on couple of Samsung Mobiles, but not getting same result on Nokia, BlackBerry & iPhone deviceas.

Please suggest me best way to get MSISDN number for all devices.

Comment: Please mark some of your questions as answered if you feel there are any answers which suit your questions.

Answer (score 9):

The ability to get the MSISDN of the user visiting the WAP site depends on a number of things.

Firstly, the user has to be on Mobile Data. If the user is on WiFi then you will not receive this information.

Secondly, the users mobile network has to support the passing of the MSISDN in the HTTP headers.

Some mobile networks send headers on all requests. Others only send if going through a specific APN. Some only send this header to specific IP addresses/blocks. I have even come across networks that send the MSISDN as a $_GET variable. You will need to check with each network that you intend to support.

For example, a particular network in South Africa used to send MSISDNs in headers until around 6 months ago, and in order to receive the MSISDN in the headers now your server address needs to be whitelisted with them.

Also remember that headers are very easy to spoof, and shouldn't be relied on unless you are guaranteed that you are the originator of the HTTP request, such as in instances where you are using Web Views inside of Android Applications - you would need to put sufficient measures in place yourself.

With all of that in mind, here is what you should be looking for:

Look through your headers for any of the following. This is not a comprehensive list of MSISDN headers at all, they are only the ones I have come across in my adventures in mobile development.

- X-MSISDN
- X_MSISDN
- HTTP_X_MSISDN
- X-UP-CALLING-LINE-ID
- X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID
- HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID
- X_WAP_NETWORK_CLIENT_MSISDN

What I do is run through the headers looking for any matches. If I don't find any matches I run through the headers again using a country-specific MSISDN regex against the values to see if there are any potential MSISDNs in the headers on keys that I do not know about. If I find a potential match I add the key and data to a list that I can go through later in order to add to my list of known MSISDN headers.

I hope this has bought some clarity. What is most important to remember is that this is not a reliable method for getting an MSISDN.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these others (*original: puedes intentar con estas otras*):

- X-MSISDN
- X_MSISDN
- HTTP-X-MSISDN
- X-UP-CALLING-LINE-ID
- X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID
- HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID
- X_WAP_NETWORK_CLIENT_MSISDN
- X-Forwarded-For
- Proxy-Client-IP
- WL-Proxy-Client-IP
- HTTP_CLIENT_IP
- HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
- x-real-ip
- HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID
- HTTP_MSISDN
- MSISDN
- User-Identity-Forward-msisdn
- HTTP_X_MSISDN
- HTTP_X_NOKIA_MSISDN
- HTTP_X_UP_SUBNO

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the headers are encrypted by the mobile operators. This may change the naming of the headers. For example X-MSISDN becomes X-ENCR-MSISDN.

Answer (score 0):

Some operators are sending x headers on server requests ,based on my recent researches ,I found out that many operators are hiding or encrypting or renaming the x headers and it's hard to retrieve the user's MSISDN , I've tried many ways and If you wanna test your operator, you can use this website Test Operator's MSISDN availablity(remember to open the link with your mobile device) I hope it will help you.I have picked up these headers by using Asp.net Mvc