# Detect a mobile number (i.e. MSISDN) over WiFi

Tags: wifi, phone-number, msisdn

Is there a way to detect a mobile number (i.e. MSISDN) from a web page a user is viewing over WiFi network?

Comment: I don't think so.  It has to be on mobile data as says here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278989/how-to-get-msisdn-number-in-wap-using-php