# Read MSISDN number using PHP, is it possible?

Tags: php

I have a problem to read MSISDN number when user connect to the internet using mobile data, the MSISDN number is used to matched with the database and validate user access. when the user access with MSISDN not in the database, the server will remind them with a notification. Is it possible to read MSISDN number using PHP?

If yess, then please tell me how, i have read some similar question such as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278989/how-to-get-msisdn-number-in-wap-using-php), but it doesn't work, it may caused by operator hide the content header.

Comment: have you got solution? Then plz share

Answer (score -1):

Hope it works

```
$header = apache_request_headers(); 
if(isset($header['x-up-calling-line-id']) && !empty($header['x-up-calling-line-id'])){ 
    $phone_number = $header['x-up-calling-line-id']; 
}
else{ $error_phone_number = "Phone number missing...!"; }
```